# Is there a away in which string.Format gives suggestion for parameters which param goes to which

Tags: c#

I am working on an application where I am working on some constants I need to figure out the parameters which I am using in **string.Format** Is there any way to give the user a suggestion on which index parameters need to be added? Here is my code

```
public readonly static string GetAgentGroupById = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:urn='urn:UMARKETSCWS' xmlns:std='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/StdQuery' xmlns:misc='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/Misc'>
                                             <soapenv:Header/>
                                             <soapenv:Body>
                                                <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                                   <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                                      <std:sessionid>{0}</std:sessionid>
                                                      <urn:agentID>{1}</urn:agentID>
                                                   </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                                </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                             </soapenv:Body>
                                          </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Here is the usage

```
string.Format(SoapConstants.GetAgentGroupById, request.sessionId, request.agentId)
```

The only thing I need to figure how the user will know the on {0} sessionId needs to be added.

Comment: What do you mean by "let the user know"? Someone who is using this string in their own code? If that's the case, I wouldn't make this string publicly available but create a method that takes the required parameters and returns the final string after the replacement

Comment: By user I mean that can be any other developer who can use my library I need to give the developer any suggestions regarding the GetAgentGroupById

Comment: As I said, don't expose the string itself but a method that takes the required parameters and returns the final ready-to-use string

Answer (score 0):

Use XML documentation:

```
/// <summary>
/// GetAgentGroupById is a template string to be used in string.Format.
/// Use SessionId as second parameter and AgentId as third.
/// Example
/// <code>
/// var getAgentGroupById = string.Format(GetAgentGroupById, sessionId, agentId);
/// </code>
/// </summary>
public readonly static string GetAgentGroupById = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:urn='urn:UMARKETSCWS' xmlns:std='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/StdQuery' xmlns:misc='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/Misc'>
                                        <soapenv:Header/>
                                        <soapenv:Body>
                                        <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                            <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                                <std:sessionid>{0}</std:sessionid>
                                                <urn:agentID>{1}</urn:agentID>
                                            </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                        </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                        </soapenv:Body>
                                    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

BTW, there are some subtle differences between a `public readonly static` variable and a `public const`, but that's for another question.

However, @derpirscher have a good point in his comment to your question - if you want to make it easier for your users, expose it as a public method and not as a field:

```
// I assume argument types to be int, of course you can change to whatever is relevant
public static string GetAgentGroupById(int sessionId, int agentId)
=> @$"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:urn='urn:UMARKETSCWS' xmlns:std='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/StdQuery' xmlns:misc='http://www.utiba.com/delirium/ws/Misc'>
                                        <soapenv:Header/>
                                        <soapenv:Body>
                                        <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                            <urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                                <std:sessionid>{sessionId}</std:sessionid>
                                                <urn:agentID>{agentId}</urn:agentID>
                                            </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentIDRequest>
                                        </urn:getAgentGroupByAgentID>
                                        </soapenv:Body>
                                    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Comment: Suppose the GetAgentGroupById is hidden then what will happen?

Comment: What do you mean by `hidden`?

Comment: @KamranKhan if it's "hidden" (whatever you mean by that) how will it be used somewhere else?

Comment: Like in other class library or DLL ?

Comment: If it's exposed in the library so is the documentation

Comment: @derpirscher I've edited your proposed solution into my answer. Should you like to post it as your own answer please let me know and I'll edit that out.